# suppress NULL output after using map

Tags: r, loops, purrr

I made a function to write a text file on the disk

```
fun <- function(text, name){
  writeLines(text, name)
}
```

But when I try to use it via `purrr::pmap`, it gives the empty list as output:

```
pmap(list(text = c("test1", "test2"), name = c("1.txt", "2.txt")), fun)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

How to suppress it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `walk` functions are designed for this purpose, here we can use `pwalk`. From the documentation of `?pmap`

> walk() returns the input .x (invisibly). This makes it easy to use in a pipe. The return value of .f() is ignored.

```
library(purrr)

pwalk(list(text = c("test1", "test2"), name = c("1.txt", "2.txt")), fun)
```

Answer (score 3):

While `walk` functions are certainly the go to option, to strictly answer your question, i.e. "*suppress NULL output after using map"*, we can use `invisible`. I am posting this with `mapply` but it works with your code as well.

```
invisible(mapply(fun, text = c("test1", "test2"), name = c("1.txt", "2.txt")))
```